# Change view in different ng-app

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to know if there is a way to change the view in an alternate ng-app? On a single page I have two ng-app. In the outer ng-app I have a navigation include which contains my entire application navigation. Inside that is an ng-app that contains the content.

I'd like to be able to click in link in the navigation under the "main" ng-app and have the view change inside the "order" ng-app. Currently if I click a link in the "main" app it refreshes the entire page instead of just the "order" app since that link is not inside the "order" app. Basically I need angular to think the navigation request came from inside the "order" ng-app.

I cannot add any links inside the "order" ng-app because the entire navigation is based on the left side of the page and I can't have two sets of navigation.
The page must be like this because everything outside the "order" ng-app is built by an MVC shared _layout page.

Thanks,
Chris.

```
<body data-ng-app="main">

    <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div ng-include="'navViews/common/navigation.html'"></div>

        <!-- Page wraper -->

        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg {{$state.current.name}}">

            <!-- Page wrapper -->
            <div ng-include="'navViews/common/topnavbar.html'"></div>

            <!-- Main view  -->

            <div class="container body-content">

<div data-ng-app="order" id="order" data-ng-controller="rootViewModel">

<h2>{{ pageHeading }}</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
<hr />

<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you creating two apps ? You can achieve the same thing in single app

Comment: The current routing for angular does not allow for this, however you can get around this if you want to build some custom routing (or maybe someone has). I just worked on a project that had completely separate requirejs modules for everything that needed custom routing built - I cannot share the companies code BUT it is doable. I would recommend going monolithic if you can though.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into ui-router. It is an alternative to ngRoute. It allows for multiple and nested views. It is very flexible.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router